# Why the UPROPERTY specifiers Visible*/Edit* are used together with BlueprintRead*

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

Unreal Engine 4 provides three specifiers to control the visibility and editability of an C++ class member exposed to Blueprint via `UPROPERTY()`.

The documentation in the [UE4 source code](https://github.com/EpicGames/UnrealEngine/blob/release/Engine/Source/Runtime/CoreUObject/Public/UObject/ObjectMacros.h) (see also [UE4 wiki](https://wiki.unrealengine.com/UPROPERTY), [UE4 documentation](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-us/Programming/UnrealArchitecture/Reference/Properties/Specifiers)) says the following regarding editability:

- For `VisibleAnywhere`, `VisibleInstanceOnly`, `VisibleDefaultsOnly`:

  > ... cannot be edited at all.
- For `EditAnywhere`, `EditInstanceOnly`, `EditDefaultsOnly`:

  > ... can be edited ...
- For `BlueprintReadOnly`:

  > ... can be read by blueprints, but not modified.

  and `BlueprintReadWrite`:

  > ... can be read or written from a blueprint.

Questions:

1. Since the `Visible*` specifiers already restrict the usage to **read only** in Blueprints, why it is used in conjunction with `BlueprintReadOnly`? Isn't the second specifier *superfluous*? Example:

   ```
   UPROPERTY(VisibleDefaultsOnly, BlueprintReadOnly)
   UMyActorComponent* MyActorComponent;
   ```
2. Even more confusing is the usage of `Edit*` specifiers, which allow **read and write** in Blueprint, together with `BlueprintReadOnly` which restricts to read only in Blueprint. Aren't both specifiers *opposing* each other? Example:

   ```
   UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadOnly)
   UMyActorComponent* MyActorComponent;
   ```
3. Are the `Visible*`/`Edit*` specifiers valid in a different context than the `BlueprintRead*` specifiers? (the question is not about `InstanceOnly` (property windows for instances), `DefaultsOnly` (property windows for archetypes) and `Anywhere` (instances & archetypes))

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**tl;dr**

- `Visible*`/`Edit*` specifiers allow you (typically a game designer) to access/modify a variable directly in Blueprint Editor for quick configurations of class properties.
- `BlueprintRead*` allow you to get/set the value of a variable in the **Event Graph** when you're doing *Visual Scripting*.

---

Explanation:

Some namings and explanations in the official documentation are indeed a little ambiguous, especially for beginners. In a nutshell, both `Visible*`/`Edit*` and `BlueprintRead*` expose a variable in a class to the **Unreal Engine**, but do different things. In fact, both question 2 and 3 can be answered via question 1. Let's see your question 1:

> Since the `Visible*` specifiers already restrict the usage to **read only** in Blueprints, why it is used in conjunction with `BlueprintReadOnly`? Isn't the second specifier superfluous? Example:
>
> `UPROPERTY(VisibleDefaultsOnly, BlueprintReadOnly)
>    UMyActorComponent* MyActorComponent;`

Here you're exposing an `ActorComponent` to the Engine. Here I'll explain a non-`Component` member variable first, because specifiers for `Component` "appears" to work differently from non-`Component` variables.

Suppose I have a `TpsCharacter` class for a Third Person Shooter character, which has the following 3 `float` variables:

```cpp
// The zooming speed
UPROPERTY(EditDefaultsOnly, BlueprintReadOnly, Category = "Camera Zoom")
float ZoomSpeed;

// The FOV after zoom in
UPROPERTY(EditDefaultsOnly, BlueprintReadOnly, Category = "Camera Zoom")
float ZoomInFov;

// The default FOV
UPROPERTY(EditDefaultsOnly, BlueprintReadOnly, Category = "Camera Zoom")
float DefaultFov;
```

They're all specified as `EditDefaultsOnly`, which means that, after we create a Blueprint class called `TpsCharacter_BP` based on this C++ class and open this Blueprint, the values of these 3 variables are editable in the **Details Panel** for this Blueprint class, as shown in the picture: [image: Blueprint Editor snapshot for TpsCharacter_BP]

Of course, by using `Visible*` specifiers, they are read-only (greyed out in the **Details Panel**) so you can't change their values.

Now let's get back to your `MyActorComponent`. Like I said, specifiers for `Component` works somewhat differently.

1. `Component` appear in the **Components Panel** together with its owner class in the Blueprint Editor instead of in **Details Panel** like a non-`Component` variable.
2. When you have neither `Visible*` nor `Edit*` specifiers for a `Component`, this `Component` itself will **always** appear in the Editor, but **you can't access properties/variables inside this Component.**, and **Details Panel** for this `Component` will be empty.
3. `Visible*` specifier allows you to access the `Component`'s properties via its **Details Panel**, just like accessing the 3 variables in my `TpsCharacter_BP` class. However, when you declare it as `Edit*`, the **Details Panel** will show wired settings, allowing you to modify the ***Pointer value*** of this `Component` rather than its contents. This is definitely one thing you should **always** avoid.

**Rule of thumb for `Component`**: **NEVER** declare them as `Edit*` because it allows you change the pointer value to point to other things; always do `Visible*`. For a non-`Component` object you're free to set `Edit*`.

Now it's much easier to understand `BlueprintRead*` specifier. Is it *superfluous* with the presence of `Visible*`? Is `BlueprintReadOnly` opposing `Edit*` specifiers? Absolutely no. Are they valid in different context? Yes. The `BlueprintRead*` specifier allows you to read/write a variable in the **Event Graph** in the Blueprint Editor, that is, when you're doing Blueprint Visual Scripting. For my `TpsCharacter` class above, since all 3 variables are declared `BlueprintReadOnly`, I can get their values inside the **Event Graph** as shown here:
[image: Get variable from Event Graph]

You can do the same for your `MyActorComponent`. By using `BlueprintReadWrite`, you can also set the value for these variables in **Event Graph**.

I write such long answer to explain because they can really confuse beginners though they're actually simple concepts.

Comment: So insightful, this really helped me understand what's going on coming from Unity